# Python split string and print desired output

Tags: python, string

```
txt = "This is + line"
for i in txt:
  if i=="+":
   print()
```

I want to write a code that will print `"This is "` when it gets `"+"`. Or up-to `"+"` string. Don't use `re` library.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
txt = "This is + line"
printtext = ""
for element in range(0, len(txt)): 
    if (txt[element] == "+"):
        print (printtext)
    printtext += txt[element]
```

going through the entire string, checking if we hit + yet, if not we add the current element to the string that we will print

@lazycoder's solution is also really nice; just printing everything before i.. Should have done that myself

Answer (score 1):

You should have posted an example to be more clear.

```
txt = "This is + line"

if len(txt.split('+')) >1:
    txt = txt.replace('+', <desired_value>)
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Use a slice with `str.index()`:

```
txt = "This is + line"
print(txt[:txt.index('+')])
```

Output:

```
This is
```

---

Another options is to use `str.find()`:

```
txt = "This is + line"
print(txt[:txt.find('+')])
```

Output:

```
This is
```